# Improving requested edits in Stack Overflow Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, user-experience

It'd be helpful to be able to improve suggested edits (or new submissions) to Stack Overflow Documentation.

This is perhaps by design, but for formatting changes, typos, etc., it's just faster and less confusing to just edit the suggestion than writing a comment.

It's been very helpful to be able to do that for normal suggestions in the question/answer edit review queue; and so should it also be here.

Perhaps the original author would then have to approve it first so that you cannot cheat the system by editing and then approving avoiding any further review (if you're the last one to approve).

Currently there's only a red error: `You cannot retract a draft you don't own.`

Comment: Here's the [relevant documentation page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes).  I agree that the "Reject" button doesn't convey "click me to improve this proposed edit!"

Comment: I posted a [related concern](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329441/documentation-better-way-to-point-out-grammar-typos?noredirect=1#comment372709_329441) today and was pointed here.  There really should be some better support for improving proposed changes.  It can be tough to point out minor improvements with only the options of a comment wall and rejection

Comment: + that you need two rejects. And it can take forever to get that second reject in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

I found out you can reject it and then improve the draft.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/13766

> "This draft is based on another draft by Enrico Maria De Angelis."

Please understand this was posted 2 hours after the question was asked and reflects the state at that time, a couple of hours after Documentation was opened. If you have an update, feel free to post. This is not endorsing this way of doing the correction in any way.

Comment: [Yes, however this answer contradicts that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328482/833070). Should we reject or should we approve?

Comment: Nice find. But this is non-intuitive then. Should be made more clear in the User-Interface.

Comment: Also, sometimes I just want to approve good example and leave the bads for editing (by the author), as I request [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328614/approve-specific-examples-only).

Comment: @Oleg in this case you'd probably just separate the bad parts out and resubmit?

Comment: then the original editor gets no rep. and you get all the rep for doing a tiny change. not optimal.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Really? There are both edits in the edit history. Anyone could steal the contribution of someone else this way.

Comment: @Draken Yea it seems more fair to approve it then edit. Otherwise the drafts need to come with NDA's :P

Comment: Note that it currently is even harder; as we now need _two_ rejections, there is not yet an improvement button if you are the first one to reject...

Comment: But it's hard to use. and this is [tag:featurerequest]

Comment: This is unworkable, especially for low traffic tags. Either with accepting then editing *or* rejecting then improving.  The former means that the original edit in need of improvement is *merged into the topic and publicly visible* until the fix is approved. The latter requires another person to catch the error and reject it before some other idiot approves it, and then requires *its own approval*.

Comment: @Comintern Sure it is not ideal, notice I posted this soon after Documentation was opened. It has also changed since I posted it. It was two approves and one reject originally, no it is the opposite.

Comment: I agree this isn't really a solution to the problem, and opens itself to people potentially rejecting someone's good edit with some minor grammatical errors and resubmitting them as their own.  Hopefully it's not a workaround too many people are taking advantage of

Comment: My take is that if I approve someone's edit, but then make my own (for further improvement), I can't approve of my own edit. Why would you trust me to approve someone's edit, but not trust me enough to approve of my own edits? Is there a reputation score I need to get before that will happen?

Comment: @NovaDev you could easily deface the content is one obvious reason

Comment: @charlietfl - true, but I would think that the reputation system that is in place should be a deterrent. I wouldn't want to lose reputation by defacing something. In fact, it's likely that the reputation system is more effective than what Wikipedia does at preventing vandalism.

Comment: @NovaDev you are thinking like an honest well intentioned person, as most do....but not all