# Incorrect usage of English in Stack Overflow Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

I've been browsing the Stack Overflow Documentation beta and found several points where people are submitting change requests, but English doesn't appear to be their strong point (Due to not being their mother tongue or something similar) or there are spelling mistakes.

Is it correct to reject these edits as they need to be reworded? Ideally, I would like to see this [question be approved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328455/improving-requested-edits-in-documentation) so I could just edit them and improve the general grammar and correct any spelling mistakes.

Apart from the language, they are factually correct, so I'm unsure on how to proceed on those types of edit requests. Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 4):

If the information in the edit is good, approve it, and then make additional edits yourself if the language is rough enough that the meaning isn't totally clear. This way the editor's contribution stands, but you get credit for your work as well.

Comment: I did see though you can also reject and then use that rejection to improve upon the said edit. Approval takes two and rejection takes one, so I'm not sure if it should be approved and hope someone picks up the language changes (In case I forget) or reject and submit as a new approval

Comment: Thanks!  Per [related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328455/improving-requested-edits-in-stack-overflow-documentation), and for consistency with Q&A suggested edits, could we have Approve / Reject / *Improve* choices on proposed Documentation changes?

Comment: Or "Approve" and "Reject/Improve" choices?  I did find the [relevant documentation page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes) just now.

Comment: I suggest [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328614/approve-specific-examples-only) to implement a selective approval of the good examples.