# Approve or reject specific examples only

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When reviewing changes to **multiple** examples in a **single** topic (by a single author), how can I approve selected examples and reject others?

**EDIT**

I want to approve edit to one example and reject another example since I think it can be built under a different section, but I want the author to reorganize the content.

1. If I understand correcly, "reject and edit" requires me to do the work?
2. Should I just comment and wait for the author to reorganize?
3. What happens if someone keeps working on a topic with many new examples, but has a bad edit on that topic? I see potential conflicts in the workflow.

**EDIT**

This related [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328455/improving-requested-edits-in-stack-overflow-documentation) suggest a feature to edit the draft directly, instead of adding comments. Although, in my case, I would like to pass the good example and leave the bad ones be until the author edits them.

Comment: Edits are per-topic, and not per-example. So what you're looking for is "reject and edit," which should give you the edit you're rejecting as a starting point — from there on, you can keep what you meant to approve, and change what you meant to reject.

Comment: I just learned this as well, @jnat. Several times I have submitted separate edits to an example and to, say, a remarks section. I used a different edit summary for both of those because, well, the edits had a different rationale. I didn't realize that they would both be collapsed into a single edit, losing my original edit summary. This UI definitely needs some work to make it more clear that, as you say, edits are per-topic not per-example. The *links* (i.e., the entry points for the feature) certainly appear to be per-example!

Comment: @JNat Why is it per-topic? It would be much easier it it was per item, I nearly never approved all the edits pending on the topic.

Answer (score 9):

PS. I was unsure whether to post as a new question (an intermediate feature request of sorts) or as an answer here. Decided on the latter, because the screenshot might support the question here as well.

As long as (or if) the full feature request is not fulfilled, I think **a quick (temporary) fix might be needed/warranted**. The reason I says so: I *accidentally* approved many examples at once, because the UI is really unclear that this is about to happen.

I used my browser's back button to see what had happened, here's a screenshot of what I saw:

[image: approval flow]

As far as I knew I clicked a link to review the "Css binding" example. So I did, and I hit "Approve" without scrolling or seeing that there was more to it.

**Please include a UX-quick-fix for if/while the main feature-request is not fulfilled.**

Some suggestions:

- Place the "Approve" button all the way down, below all changes, requiring you to scroll. (Or, failing that, when I scroll, move along the box in the sidebar.)
- Make the text more prominent, or even part of the button ("Approve 4 examples, 1 edit, 6 additions, 5 deleteions" or something similar).

Comment: IMHO, this is worth a separate feature request. I have run into this same issue, and would love to see it fixed. One other possible fix: completely hide (instead of just collapse) any examples that have not been changed, so you can see the next edit without scrolling.