# What do I do when a documentation edit is helpful, but introduces minor formatting or grammatical issues which are easily corrected?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Now that documentation is in open beta, the flood of new edits has given me the opportunity to review many more changes than I had in the past.

One situation I've noticed coming up a lot is that an edit will improve a topic quite a bit overall, but also introduce some issues which should be corrected before the edit is approved.

I hesitate to hit reject because usually the vast majority of the added content is quite helpful, it's only a few minor bits which need to be corrected. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328455/1157054

Answer (score 5):

**Click Reject**

After you vote to reject the edit, the UI will present an option to improve the edit:

[image: Rejected by Ajedi32, Improve Draft]

Comment: Just to note, I've had this happen to me, and it was very helpful.

Comment: I've rejected the change, but now I see STATUS: **Awaiting approval** and no way to edit to fix minor errors.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Doesn't it require two votes now to reject an edit? I wonder if that change broke this part of the system, so this button only appears for the final reject voter...