# Documentation addition rejected yet added by user that rejected it

Tags: discussion, documentation

I just want to understand the scope of documentation requests/approvals/etc. I suggested the creation of ["References (Draft)"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/47380?draftId=40510) in PHP Language and had it rejected - understandably due to a few things that I ended up changing/ammending.

Following the rejection of said suggestion - ["References"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/3468/references#t=201607250312059668242) ended up being created with minimal changes (*mostly code renaming*) by said user that rejected it without core body content being changed... evident when run through an [online Diff Checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/).

I'm not here to rep-whore. I just want to understand how it's claimed by another user after having generated said content.

I just don't want this to turn onto "greedy" users rejecting suggested edits/drafts with the sole purpose of generating it themselves for the gain.

Comment: P.s.: There was really not _that_ much to do. After all, I mostly complained about the examples in the last iteration. … I had also complained about one other thing, but forgot about that and submitted another edit about it a bit later. (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/47486)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm *that said user*. Thus, apologies if you think this was badly handled by me.

---

I've not immediately improved your draft. I've waited 30 minutes after the rejection (to give you more time to react) and then decided to improve the few parts which still were problematic. [I did not know whether you were planning to pursue it or not, thus took it into my own hands — it already were about 80 minutes since my initial comment.]

After all, most of the content was fine. I'd loved to be able to suggest a correction on your draft instead (see also [Improving requested edits in Stack Overflow Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328455/improving-requested-edits-in-stack-overflow-documentation)), but there's no such thing and the only way was to click improve, do the few changes I found missing and then submit it myself.

Also, on the change page https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/47474 there is noted "This draft is based on [another draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/drafts/40510) by [Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518525/darren)." as you see I've not just copied it all in my own new change, but it's actually built on yours. Just in the edit history of that topic your contribution isn't displayed anymore.

---

So, regarding the *purpose of generating it themselves for the gain*:

In general, I think the implementation of the documentation has to be blamed for this. When improving anothers change, it should still show up in the actual history of the topic, and not just in a loosely linked list of the drafts. That way you would get the main credit and I'd get as much credit as appropriate (depending on whether it's substantial or not).

I've created a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for this: [Give credit for authors of an original draft](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329368/give-credit-for-authors-of-an-original-draft).

Comment: If the topic was something you could build on, why didn't you accept the change instead of reject it? Like many collaborative endeavors the first draft need not be perfect. As long as a contributor is making progress, their improvements should be accepted. (I do however agree it ought to be easier to do that dance.)

Comment: @JonEricson I don't fundamentally disagree, but it probably also depends on the attitudes of the people. Some people only want to let _good_ changes go through. [And avoid temporarily having not a perfect example on the topic.] Others are fine with it and just put a quick change on top of it. It's also not very intuitive by the UI what the actual recommended actions are in that case.

Comment: @bwoebi I was in the process of editing the content as you'd suggested in your comments, only to be greeted with a closed message directly after yourself and another user denied the proposal. This ended up not allowing me to amend/modify. So to clarify, I did take your suggestions on board and was editing the content, but there was too much haste in closing it, not allowing me to update.

Comment: @Darren uh, but then Status would have changed to retracted? But still, you'd have had plenty of time after it to click the improve button and suggest a new proposal? But anyway, I'm sorry this went badly :-/

Comment: @Darren That it didn't allow you to update is bad, it should have created a new proposal instead from your draft... Sounds like a bug then?

Comment: @bwoebi - Didn't take/do it directly through SO - I had it copy/pasted in notepad (*as I had accidentally discarded an edit, deleting the whole proposal -.-*) and was ammending changes. Look it's alright man, I just didn't want to have users take advantage of something like this.

Comment: @bwoebi I'll admit I did feel hard done by when I saw it all (with the slight changes) and assumed the worst. I'm following your feature request and feel it's a good suggestion!

Comment: @Darren I'm very much sorry, but next time, please just click the button to retract first, then I know you're on it!

Comment: @bwoebi call me old-fashioned haha - I didn't know it was a race! But following this, will do so. We're all good regardless man!

Comment: @Darren The situation could be even uglier. My example was copied, a moderator resolved that, but the user still tried to delete my repost because I had a jsfiddle.net there. I didn't know it is a bad practice to show the code there too. jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330300/my-topic-was-rejected-then-it-was-copied-with-the-same-code-and-my-image-and-ap?noredirect=1#comment376887_330300

Comment: @bwoebi I like your answer, it is nice that you explained. The user who did that for my topic, didn't improve anything and still want to delete the example I reposted.