# Give credit for authors of an original draft

Tags: feature-request, documentation, revision-history, documentation-proposals

#### Background

So, we encountered just this situation: [Documentation addition rejected yet added by user that rejected it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329361/documentation-addition-rejected-yet-added-by-user-that-rejected-it)

An user made a largely great proposal with a few things not perfect. Thus, the proposal got rejected.

After a while, I clicked the *Improve* button, made the few changes necessary … and apart from a small hint inside the proposal, there was no evidence of the contributions by the original author.

#### Suggestion

Include all the revisions of a proposal and their authors into the edit history of the topic/examples and give them appropriate credit for their contributions when the proposal gets approved.

Comment: Precedent: improving a suggested (Q&A) edit grants the +2 rep from editing and leaves the suggester's name in the edit history.

Comment: I'm said user, and I 100% do endorse this request. There was a misunderstanding on both parts with this. Myself; not clicking the "retract" to show intention (*instead, editing locally*), and @bwoebi's eagerness to get it up/mistaking my non-response for no response at all :P. He's modified it and continued on. I feel if the draft is continued on as noted above, it should be noted visibly as an initial revision/in the edit history/etc with appropriate credits.

Comment: The original draft could have been bare, or wildly different from the latest version.

Comment: @AndyHayden The edit review queue (for q&a) has the interesting feature "reject and improve" or "accept and improve" … the former gives no credit, the latter does. That's perhaps worth a consideration.

Answer (score -2):

Your suggestion, including "all the revisions of a proposal and their authors into the edit history of the topic/examples" is not a solution.

I had this problem, my example was copied word by word after was rejected and it wasn't nice. [My topic was rejected, then it was copied with the same code and my image and approved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330300/my-topic-was-rejected-then-it-was-copied-with-the-same-code-and-my-image-and-ap?noredirect=1#comment376887_330300)

Why I say it is not a solution your suggestion? I was in "the other" side in this situation. I wanted to create a topic, I wrote it and I wanted to post it. I saw a notification that other user submitted a proposal and I review it. His example was from the internet, the description was from other website without any attribution. I asked for improvements, but that was not a good proposal and I don't think, in this case, that example should be mentioned when the topic will be created. Anyway, the drafts are saved right now and anyone can see them.

It must be a better solution and **until then we can start by being more careful with what we approve, so an example not need too many updates.**

Comment: It would be a solution for the issue the OP and that said user came across, it just wouldn't be a solution that would have been helpful to what happened to you. Your issue is an entirely different one than the one which is being discussed here.

Comment: @ThomasYates What I want to say is I really understand the situation presented, but including "all the revisions of a proposal and their authors into the edit history of the topic/examples" is not good for any case.

Comment: @MadalinaTiana the issue here is that the original author can not clearly be seen as such. The proposal is to make sure they are shown somewhere more visible along with all other authors. This is about clearly showing authors (thus providing credit) and would be a good improvement towards the documentation.

Comment: @ThomasYates What if the author's original topic is copied from a website without any attributions? Not every time should be visible. I think solution is proper verification for the topics. In this way,  so no good proposal will be rejected, no wrong examples will be approved.

Comment: @MadalinaTiana If the content is copied from another website then the content must be removed unless it has been permitted by the original author. But that's not the issue here. I think you misunderstand what is being suggested, have you read and understood the issue which occurred in the post linked in the OP?

Comment: @ThomasYates "Suggestion: Include all the revisions of a proposal and their authors into the edit history of the topic/examples and give them appropriate credit for their contributions when the proposal gets approved."

Comment: @ThomasYates A topic can be proposed by an user, rejected and created by other users.

Comment: @ThomasYates What I say it is a rule for this can be useful, but can create other problems too, like attributions for a user that don't deserve.

Comment: @ThomasYates We need a more general solution.