# My topic was rejected, then it was copied with the same code and my image and approved

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, documentation, documentation-drafts

What I can do about this problem and more important, how we can prevent this? My topic was rejected, then it was copied with the same code and my image and approved.

1. Obviously, the system must be improved. Something that was rejected, the same was subsequently approved.
2. Someone just copied all my work, included my code and my image that I still have on my computer and posted them like is his own example.

In my activity I have this, but is not approved, and now the user that edited the draft had posted this. It can be an error from the website? https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/4258/outlines/15953/outline-style#t=201608011035071532272

[image]

[image]

I don't want to contribute to the Documentation if someone can just reject my topic and then post them.

UPDATE: I accepted the answer because it seems the only action possible right now. I made a request until to post the question here, but I hoped it is a solution to prevent problems like mine.

That example was deleted and I submitted my example again.

I really hope this was an isolated incident.

Important: Please don't try to delete the example again and again. It was edited by that user again because he wanted to remove a link to https://jsfiddle.net/ (and points I suppose), but now it is my original example and it is no need to downvote it or remove it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you link to your rejected proposal?

Comment: It is in the question, http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/4258/outlines/15953/outline-style#t=201608011035071532272

Comment: A link to the proposal of yours that was rejected would be better. This is just to a topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/4481/outline#t=2016072904371232

Comment: I do not know if it can be seen by anyone.

Comment: In fact, I think it is strange that he could delete the example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/revisions/4481?exampleId=15672

Comment: What happened was that the topic "Outline" was considered to be a duplicate of the topic "Outline property". So the user deleted the duplicate topic, but thought your example to be worth saving, so they moved it over there.

Comment: No, the problem was my example contained also syntax and they said is wrong to have all the values in one single example. You can see that only the example was deleted then other user posted it.

Comment: I don't like someone can just delete an example and the repost it.

Comment: Anyway, what you see there, my example, is a draft saved in the archive. The new topic don't mention the original example.

Comment: Your change was actually approved: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/53721   Then the topic was deleted due to being a duplicate.  That user should have used the "move example" functionality instead of deleting and then manually copy/pasting your example.

Comment: I currently have a feature request for exactly that... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329368/give-credit-for-authors-of-an-original-draft

Comment: Does voting system work when submitting doc examples? How many votes are required to delete an example? Who approves examples? Can they disregard user votes on that example?

Comment: This kind of problem wouldn't have warranted a need for a meta discussion if the documentation doesn't generate any reputation.

Comment: Went through the same thing recently.. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329361/2518525

Comment: @nhahtdh This is not true! I received 2 points when I reposted my example. The problem was the user copied even the print screen, the code, the description that was rejected and posted the example again. It feels really wrong. Anyway, the system is not ok. After I posted again that, he tried to delete it because I had a link to jsfiddle.net and in the end he could update the example and delete only the link, because someone approved.

Comment: It isn't a jsfiddle link a good practice?

Comment: @nhahtdh I really don't want to contribute to the Documentation if someone can anytime to delete my topics/ example. I do this because for me is a way to improve my skills, how I explain something, code (in English). The points are just a way to let others users I'm an active user.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina It's funny that you raised this question and rejected an entire edit where I added information to a few examples and remarks in [CSS Selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/71213?draftId=59411) because you misunderstood only one example's adjustment. In the Mozilla URL you left in the rejection's reason, a descendant selector is typically defined with a single space. I just added that it is possible to add several spaces or new lines instead of just  a single one, as mentioned in the "dual purpose of CSS white space" in that same page you referred to.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina it's your own decision to stop contributing, but please do not stop others from doing so. If you feel you can add or readjust the wording, I suggest you consider the entire edit and if there's nothing critically wrong, then the right course of action is to approve and make adjustments after.

Comment: @CPHPython I didn't find your edit completely correct, but I commented that so you can see and review, I didn't copied your modifications or something like that.

Comment: @CPHPython I'm sorry you think I was wrong, I tried to avoid that you alter the work of that user without a more careful verification.

Comment: @CPHPython I really though it will be a second user that will review the update. I think yesterday I was a little affected by the fact anyone can  change your work without proper attention. Again, I'm sorry if I was wrong. This is what I'm trying to say. One user who review, or even two are not enough.

Comment: @CPHPython You have a draft I suppose. You can submit again the changes and someone will see if I was wrong. Anyway, I will be more careful the next time. I wanted to help, not to upset someone. L

Comment: @MadalinaTaina alright, don't worry too much about it. It's just that in your verification of those [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) maybe you skipped their third example (where they divide the selector into 2 lines?). Anyway, if you found that part was not correct, all the other edits I made to the remaining examples would be lost... I guess [examples need to be edited individually as it's being suggested](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330348/6225838), but for now it's easier (and others will appreciate) if you approve and reedit. Thanks!

Comment: @CPHPython I understand what you say. I thought it is better that you review the updates and repost the request. The update was a little confusing and I hesitated and it seems my decision was wrong in the end. Thank for the advice, it is useful.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I blame this mostly on the system not having a defined workflow for cases where someone wants to make a small change prior to or *while* approving something. The default for this should *always* be to approve good content, and *then* go back and make whatever tweaks you feel it needs.

Rejecting and then posting again certainly isn't the manner that we envisioned anyone going about it, I think it's rather rare that someone would consider that the best option, but it still shows that the review system is lackluster.

Kevin and Jarrod are working on just putting a full-blown review-style interface on this, which should offer a *much* less complicated and obvious workflow for those instances.

While that's happening, just (generally for anyone reading) *approve* good content by default, then make additional edits as necessary.

Comment: Kevin and Jarrod better show up with _one hell of a damn awesome_ interface. Nothing less is acceptable `:)`

Comment: @tim-post You think it is possible we have an alert on the Documentation page, with this message, "Approve good content by default, then make additional edits as necessary."? I find it useful. Anyway, "good content" is subjective right now. I think not any user should be able to reject something.

Comment: @timp-post  Related the UI, I really want a button for the search field. I know a lot of UX designers think it is no need for it and I saw this debate today on http://ux.stackexchange.com/, but I always click on "request topic" button because it is so close...

Comment: @MadalinaTaina Uhm, I found this on UX.SE and it's suggesting exactly the opposite: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/126/do-you-need-a-search-button-with-a-search-box

Comment: @bwoebi The answer is "Yes, it's absolutely needed for non-technical audience." and also check http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/96334/should-i-provide-a-button-in-case-users-dont-think-to-press-enter/97576?noredirect=1#comment157343_97576 and http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/why-is-it-inaccessible-to-create-a-form-with-no-submit-button

Comment: @MadalinaTaina And implied subtext is _and as it is commonly added for non-technical audience, this also creates expectations for technical audience and thus should be always included_. It's just an emphasis on non-technical audience where it is _even more_ critical.

Comment: @bwoebi Anyway, in this case, the "request topic" is too close... I think a button for search can help and for me would be nice to have it. It is just my opinion... I don't know if it is a must-have.

Answer (score 15):

I'm new here. So don't get me wrong - but can't you just flag it?

Flag it with another reason than mentioned in the list, explain what happened. There is no fool-proof way to detect this happening so this is your best bet.

If wrong action were to be taken then you can post about it and question the action taken along with a proposal or ask for proposals to help prevent wrong action being taken. But until then, flag it?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Yes, I can flag the example, I did that in fact, but that example is ok. What is not ok is that someone can do this, delete an example/ reject it and then post it again. I need to know how we can prevent that in first place. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina there is no way for the system to detect this. Even if content was checked against deleted content then anyone could simply add a line and the system would let the new one pass. Your only option is to flag it and hope a moderator takes correct action and punishes the user from doing this again. I'm 100% sure if you explained what happened in the flag comment then everything will be resolved and you can re-post your thing or a moderator will revive it.

Comment: PLagiarism is a legitimate reason to invoke moderator intervention. Just explain in the note, adding links to everything.

Comment: What I think is more strange is my original example was rejected, then deleted and the same content was approved. Maybe this is the real problem, how easy is to delete / reject something in the Documentation.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina then you must question whether it is too easy to delete/reject something. But that's already been asked (a lot of times), so you can up vote those questions and hope they do change the delete/reject "approval" minimum.

Comment: @ThomasYates Thank you for your comments. Maybe this is a reason more to change the delete/ reject "approval" minimum.  I didn't even notice at first. I realised my example was replaced after I checked what categories were the least active in CSS topic.

Comment: Someone suggested in a comment that maybe the user moved the topic and wanted to keep the example that was not yet approved. Maybe it is true, but it seems wrong that could do that.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina in a way that is wrong, yes. But remember - it's still beta ;)

Comment: @ThomasYates After my request, a moderator resolved this: "Handling improvement requests: taken from another author" . It is nice this, the support. I hope in the future, problems like this will be prevented in some way.

Comment: I really thought this is enough, but then I saw the user who copied my answer word by word rejected my example, "STATUS:  
 Rejected by ScientiaEtVeritas Other: Bad Formatting, Difference between outline and border already described on Overview example". In fact, I created that topic, but the example was definitively mine, so I sent the request for that only. This system is really not ok.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina I rejected his request for deletion but do believe your example must be improved (so I flagged it for improvement). You may look at other examples of other people (which are highly voted) and mimic their text formatting. If you improve your example and he requests a deletion again even if the improvements suffice then we'll take this to a moderator again. If you do not improve your example then it may eventually be deleted and would be justified.

Comment: @ThomasYates I never include in the examples a lot of notes, but in this case other user have asked for that difference between borders and outline there. The example has code, a screen capture, a link to a jsfiddle. I will review the example, but is the same example I had before and he copied. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: @ThomasYates You think that "This example does not sufficiently illustrate the point and needs to be edited to provide more details.", but is a complete example. Also, the moderator has rejected his request, but is your request now that ask for improvements.

Comment: @ThomasYates It's often computationally infeasible, but there are ways to detect nearly-identical documents, shingling and permutations being one unscalable approach

Comment: This answer is wrong, since the interface is misleading. See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329025/6083675

Comment: @Laurel I posted this question because I never thought that the solution was only to flag the answer. Now I think the interface that should be improved is exactly the reason that make the moderators offer quick support for Documentation problems. I started to think this could be updated and could work.