# Documentation - Better Way to Point out Grammar/Typos

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Right now, comments are our best way of pointing out minor problems with proposed changes, but it could be very difficult to pinpoint an instance of grammatical or spelling issues.  For large proposed changes, it's difficult to leave any good feedback regarding specific issues of these types without leaving blocks of comment attempting to describe the location of the error.

I can understand that comments are a simple way to provide feedback, but they feel a little under-powered with regards to, in effect, contributing to someone's edit.  And we probably don't want people approving faulty documentation just so they can fix the changes themselves and put the same changes up for approval again, which may result without being able to effectively point out minor English-isms in topics.

Could there be a method of highlighting/referencing parts of a proposed change, so the author can quickly find and understand grammatical/spelling issues with their post?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328455/improving-requested-edits-in-stack-overflow-documentation

Comment: Viewed and upvoted (the request, not the first answer, I left some words with regards to that approach...)